# Use of right tense

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

Can we say:

**Now it's 05:05 pm. We haven't finished the work yet when they have already arrived.**

Is it a correct sentence? Is there any problem about it?

Comment: No, it's not "valid / idiomatic". But it would be if you changed ***when*** to ***and***.

Answer (score 0):

I would have written this as:

`It's now 05:05pm. We haven't finished our|this work yet, but they have already arrived.`

Choice between `our` or `this` would depend on the context. `the` doesn't really fit unless you replace `work` with something specific.

Is this meant to be a written piece or spoken out loud, as the first phrase doesn't fit well with either mode.

Comment: Okay, then can we turn all the pasrt into past? Like, "It was 05:05pm. We hadn't finished our|this work yet, but they had already arrived"

Comment: If the rest of the context fits, then that's fine.
The use of `05:05 pm` still grates though - the rest of the piece sounds like spoken English, but a native would be very unlikely to describe the time that way.